# Rails production bootstrap-sass error on precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, assets, precompile

Everything is working great with my rails app in development environment. But when I try it in production mode I get this error when I'm doing some precompile :

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for true:TrueClass
/home/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.4.1/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb:8:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
```

I already tried multiples solutions found but none works so far.

I tried to add `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` into `config/application.rb` without success...

Comment: Did you run a bundle install in production mode? `RAILS_ENV=production bundle install`. Maybe a required gem isn't in your production group but is in your development group.

Comment: @Alexander Yes I just did it but nothing changed :/

Comment: The line its failing on tries to add to the `config.assets.precompile` array, but its not an array its `true`.  Is it possible that you have `config.assets.precompile = true` somewhere in your app?

Comment: Thanks @infused I had it in my code...

Answer (score 0):

As @infused pointed out, there was a `config.assets.precompile = true` somewhere in my code that was create this error. Removing it resolved this issue !